# Spaghettification on quarks?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, quarks, pair-production, confinement

Imagine a nucleon falls into a black hole, I would expect the gravitational force acting on each quark to be drastically different but due colour confinement wouldn't there more pairs of quarks being spawned. Would this adds even more mass to the black hole and where do this energy comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar issue arises outside the context of quantum gravity. This question is similar to asking where the energy comes from to elastically distort a solid object under gravitational tidal force as an object falls.

For example, consider Newton’s famous (but possibly apocryphal) apple falling from the tree. The Earth’s gravitational field is not uniform but radial, and dependent on the distance from the center of the Earth, so a very tiny deformation of the apple occurs, and this deformation changes the interatomic forces and the elastic energy associated with them.

So, assuming the elastic energy increases, where does it come from? Simply from the kinetic energy of the falling apple.

By this argument, I claim that no “extra” energy gets added to the black hole. If a neutron falls in from rest, the mass of the black hole simply increases by the neutron mass, 1.675e-27 kg.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows how black holes and quantum mechanics go. Whoever answers this question becomes world famous.

Comment: For clarification, I didn’t want to post this as an answer but the mods made me.

Comment: i can testify ;P

Comment: For further clarification: it was an ordinary user, rather than any of the diamond moderators, who repeatedly encouraged you to move this answer out of the [comments section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Thanks for doing so!